# data validation range Django and xlsxwriter

Tags: python, django, xlsxwriter

I have been using Django and xlsxwriter on a project that I am working on.  I want to use data_validation in Sheet1 to pull in the lists that I have printed in Sheet2.  I get the lists to print, but am not seeing the data_validation in Sheet1 when I open the file. Any insight on what I am doing incorrectly is much appreciated!

```
wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook(TestCass)
sh_1 = wb.add_worksheet()
sh_2 = wb.add_worksheet()
col = 15
head_col = 0


for header in headers:
    sh_1.write(0,head_col,header)
    sh_2.write(0,head_col,header)
    list_row = 1
    list = listFunction(headerToModelDic[header])
    for entry in list:
        sh_2.write(list_row,col,entry)
        list_row += 1
    sh_1.data_validation(1,col,50,col,{'validate':'list','source':'=Sheet2!$A2:$A9'})
    col += 1
wb.close()
```

Note: The reason I am not pulling the list directly from the site is because it is too long (longer than 256 characters).  Secondly, I ultimately would like the source range in the data validation to take in variables from sheet2, however I cannot get sheet 1 to have any sort of data validation as is so I figured I would start with the absolute values.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the data ranges are wrong in the example. It appears that you are writing out the list data in a column but the data validation refers to a row of data.

Maybe in your full example there is data in that row but in the example above there isn't.

I've modified your example slightly to a non-Django example with some sample data. I've also changed the data validation range to match the written data range:

```
import xlsxwriter

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
sh_1 = wb.add_worksheet()
sh_2 = wb.add_worksheet()
col = 15
head_col = 0

headers = ['Header 1']

for header in headers:
    sh_1.write(0,head_col,header)
    sh_2.write(0,head_col,header)
    list_row = 1
    list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    for entry in list:
        sh_2.write(list_row,col,entry)
        list_row += 1
    sh_1.data_validation(1,col,50,col,
                         {'validate':'list','source':'=Sheet2!$P2:$P6'})
    col += 1
wb.close()
```

And here is the output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! I am able to get the data validation to populate correctly now.  My other question would be is: Is there a way I could write the source range in the data validation to include variables instead of set ranges?  For example, I'm hoping that the list range in column A in Sheet2 are the options for the data validation in column A in sheet1 and the list range for column B in Sheet2 corresponds with the list options in column B of sheet1 and so on.

Comment: That seems like a question that would be easiest to figure out in Excel and then applies to the XlsxWriter program. You can play around with [absolute references](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_cell_notation.html#relative-and-absolute-cell-references) (cells prefixed by a $ sign) and relative references (without the $ sign). These affect how the validation is applied to ranges.